# Angular2 :"Select" option should be selected and visible by default

Tags: angular

Facing issues for select option in angular2.It is not selected and visible by default.It is working in IE browser but not in other browser.

country.html :

```
<label class="control-label  col-sm-offset-1  col-sm-2 bodySmall" for="country">Country:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-3" [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': country.errors  && (country.dirty || country.touched)}">
                    <select class="form-control bodySmall" id="country" [(ngModel)]="model.country" name="country" #country="ngModel" required>
                        <!--required-->

                        <option value="" selected="selected">--Please select a Country--</option>
                        <option *ngFor="let c of countries" [value]="c">{{c}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <div *ngIf="country.errors && (country.dirty || country.touched)" class="help-block">
                        <div [hidden]="!country.errors.required">Country is required.</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

[image: FYR Please find screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are wanting to have a non-selectable item(user cannot manually select it) preselected by default, then try something like this:

```
<option disabled hidden [value]="undefined">Please select a Country</option>
```

The `[value]=undefined` can make it preselected if you don't populate a valid value.  The disabled and hidden make the option not manually selectable by the user.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set default value use:

```
<option disabled selected value>-- Please select a Country --</option>
```

if you have default value loaded in component in selectedCountry  on init add:

```
<option *ngFor="let c of countries" [selected]="selectedCountry  == 'c'" >{{c}}</option>
```